# ¿Cómo soluciono este problema de mapeo UV en Unity? (no muestra las texturas correctamente)

Tags: unity3d

Tengo un conjunto de assets, hechos en `blender`, con una textura `atlas` para meter todos los assets en una sola textura.

El problema es que al exportar a `unity`, esas coordenadas `UV` se rompen.

---

Los assets como se ven en blender:

[image: http://imgur.com/a/C4toy]

---

El problema en unity al mostrar los assets:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Deberían verse bien, supongo que en `unity` en la llamada al objeto, hay una deforma en la escala, pero me asegure de haber rotado, escalado (aplicado bien las transformaciones en blender antes de exportar).

Comment: ¿en que formato importas los modelos a unity? se supone que copiando el modelo ".blend" al directorio de tu proyecto (en unity) y arrastrando la textura al objeto en la escena debería bastar.

Answer (score 1):

Creo que es muy posible que solucione su problema de esta manera:

*(si no lo ha solucionado ya pues la pregunta es algo antigua pero no la habia visto).*

Selecione el o los modelos, supongamos que esta en el directorio `prefabs`, busque la pestaña `inspector`, donde le apareceran los botones: <kbd>Model</kbd> <kbd>Rig</kbd> <kbd>Animation</kbd> pulse sobre <kbd>Model</kbd> y active el **check** con el nombre **Swap UV**, se le activaran unos botones mas abajo con el nombre <kbd>Revert</kbd> y <kbd>Apply</kbd> pulse sobre <kbd>Apply</kbd>.